# sending 4 parameters in one object or one object array to rest API response

Tags: json, laravel, rest, api, response

I am learning RestAPI. I want to send 4 parameters in one object to response.

Code:

```
 return response()->json(['success'=>true,'message'=>'success', 'data' => array($my_total_credit,$latest_credit_date,$my_total_buyers,$total_payment_requests)]);
```

With above code I am getting response like below:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "success",
    "data": [
        75000,
        "2019-10-24",
        3,
        4
    ]
}
```

In above code I am sending array to data. 
Expected: But now I want response of one object or object array that will have above 4 parameters like below:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "success",
    "data": [{
     "parameter1": "75000",
     "parameter2": "2019-10-24",
     "parameter3": "3",
     "parameter4":  "4"
    }]
}
```

How I will get expected response?
Please guide.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
$my_total_credit = ...;
...

return response()->json([
  'success'=>true,
  'message'=>'success', 
  'data' => array(array(
      "parameter1" => $my_total_credit,
      "parameter2" => $latest_credit_date,
      "parameter3" => $my_total_buyers,
      "parameter4" => $total_payment_requests 
  ))
]);
```

And If you can get this data from database query, you can only do this:

```php
$data = Model::where('xxx')->selectRaw(
    'xxx AS parameter1, xxx AS parameter2, xxx AS paramter3'
  )->first();
return response()->json([
  'success'=>true,
  'message'=>'success', 
  'data' => array($data)
]);
```

Try to test the php array for response by `json_encode()`

```php
>>> $a=[[1 => '2342', 2 => 'fsaf']]
>>> json_encode($a, true)
=> "[{"1":"2342","2":"fsaf"}]"  # output

>>> $a=[1 => '234', 2=> 'fasa']
>>> json_encode($a, true)
=> "{"1":"234","2":"fasa"}" # output
=>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just need some more information regarding this. I am getting response like ```{
    "success": true,
    "message": "success",
    "data": {
        "parameter1": 75000,
        "parameter2": "2019-10-24",
        "parameter3": 3,
        "parameter4": 4
    }
}``` how data `[ ]` changed to `{ }`? also i am getting data from 4 different queries. Can you please update your answer?

Comment: @ganesh I have update my answer, and may be your 4 different queries can be changed to one.

Comment: First code works perfect. I am not understanding your second code. I have 4 different queries with different models

Comment: If your  4 models have relationship..., may be can select them by one sql query.